# assets in Symfony6 - manifest.json missing

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm learning Symfony, following a tuto. Problem is, it is with Symfony5 and i'm using Symfony6.
The tuto says to create an assets folder in public directory, which I did :

[image: structure]

When I use Twig to call my bootstrap.css like this :
`<link href="{{ assets('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' )}}" rel="stylesheet">`

I get this error :
`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laboutiquefr/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist. Did you forget to build the assets with npm or yarn?").`

My questions are :

- How do I fix this manifest.json error ?
- I see an assets folder with Symfony6, which is not on the tuto with Symfony5. Should I use this folder instead ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build asset when updating css/js/images by using the command:

`yarn encore dev --watch` when using yarn or `npm run watch` when using npm.

This should build your assets (and create a manifest.json referencing those assets).